# Google Maps: setCenter and panTo not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following Google Maps v3 JS code to change the current map center location:

```
//current map center:40.714409999999994,-74.00598000000004 (New York, NY)

    //destination map center: 40.765789515305165,-80.32365839672855 Beaver Falls, PA
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.765789515305165,-80.32365839672855);
    console.log('center b4:');
    console.log(VZ.MDU.Map.map.getCenter());
    VZ.MDU.Map.map.setCenter(latLng);
    console.log('center after:');
    console.log(VZ.MDU.Map.map.getCenter());
```

The problem is, when I call setCenter; the map doesn't change location; it's still showing downtown NYC instead of Beaver Falls, PA. When I call map.getCenter before and after the call to .setMap; the center remains the same after the map.setCenter call. I also tried panTo, but that doesn't do anything either. I'm not getting any JS errors, it just doesn't change the map location.

Any helpful advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem.you are not passing anything in last call ofsetCeter (inside console.log). I Changed them as string.
Changed

```
//current map center:40.714409999999994,-74.00598000000004 (New York, NY)

    //destination map center: 40.765789515305165,-80.32365839672855 Beaver Falls, PA
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.765789515305165,-80.32365839672855);
    console.log('center b4:');
    console.log("VZ.MDU.Map.map.getCenter()");
    VZ.MDU.Map.map.setCenter(latLng);
    console.log('center after:');
    console.log("VZ.MDU.Map.map.getCenter()");
```