# Google Maps setCenter not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

I've checked [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907762/google-maps-v3-setcenter-moves-pos-to-top-left?lq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714362/google-maps-setcenter-and-panto-not-working) on StackOverflow relating to setCenter and google maps in IE8 but none of them seem to describe the problem I'm seeing. My javascript code constructs map objects inside collapsible divs, and due to the implementation of google maps a resize/re-center operation is required when showing the divs.

The code works fine in IE9/10, Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but doesn't work in IE8 - the resize works OK but the map is not centred, rather the marker appears at the top left, just outside the viewable area (suggesting that the setCenter call is doing nothing).

Resize/center code below:

```
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter(center);
```

Comment: The marker appearing at the top left corner indicates to me that the API can't get a non-zero size for the map container.

Comment: @geocodezip Surely if that were the case the resize event wouldn't work either? The map displays correctly (and before I added the code to trigger the resize event the map display was broken across browsers because at map initialization time it was in a div of size zero due to the collapsed container)

Comment: Use `map.panTo(center);`

Comment: @PremshankarTiwari Nope, that doesn't work either. I could probably code a hack which detects IE8 and then does a panBy call for the correct number of pixels but that would be pretty horrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of why this doesn't work under IE8. In the end I coded an unpleasant hack which detects IE8 and pans the container manually to center the map, but I'd love to replace it with something less ugly if anyone has a solution...